# Why css rotate messes up child's skew

Tags: css, transform

take a look this is div without parent being rotated only skew and then child skewed back.

child(redbox):
**skewed:**-40deg

parent: **skewed:** 40deg

how it looks...

[image]

No if i only just rotate parent why does the red box gets messed up...

child(redbox):
**skewed:**-40deg

parent: **skewed:** 40deg **rotated:** 40deg.

[image]

so whyyyy does just rotating parent messes up the whole thing so confused.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IyBvt

i think skewed is getting applied after rotation or something

Comment: in fact now that i notice rotating also messes up the parent div.

Comment: Your transform-origin's are different. If you set them both to `bottom right`, and remove the transform for the child div, they both rotate properly. http://jsbin.com/iYiqaVe/1

Comment: i want the child div to rotate...??? i dont want to **remove** the transform on child!!

Comment: The code in my jsbin was an exact copy of the code from your codepen.io (you however changed the code in the jsbin link you posted.) Obviously if you want the child to be transformed, then do so.

Comment: read question...skew works only till its rotated. rotation messes up skewing. Basically its rotated first then skewed. your code in jsbin wont work and it needs -webkit- whereas you dont need that in codepen. At least check that your code is working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you do it, the skew of the parent and the skew of the child are not aligned anymore.

If you set this style to the parent, they are:

```
.box {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  transition: transform 1s linear;
  transform: rotate(40deg) skewy(40deg);
  transform-origin: right bottom;
  transform-style: preserve-3D;
}
```

Notice that the only change that I have made is changing the order, from

```
  transform: skewy(40deg) rotate(40deg) ;
```

To

```
  transform: rotate(40deg) skewy(40deg);
```

Also notice that now, the skew of the child, even though it is specified as "Y", is happening at 40 deg (because it is inside the 40deg rotation)

Comment: i realized that it was order that mattered. i thought first action is performed first but it starts from last one. What does preserve 3d is supposed to do here

Comment: preserve 3d isn't doing anything here, since these are 2D transforms. I included it because it was in your codepen, and I copied it, but it is pretty useless.

Comment: scrap that what i said before what actually happens is this: skewing on child happens as if it was never rotated even if parent has been rotated. So to get desired effect, need to rotate it back and then skew. skewing doesn't change direction regardless of element or its parent has been rotated. To it north side is 0 degrees.