# how to choose what transform is applied first in css

Tags: css

problem: i want to skew box than rotate it but what happens is that it gets rotated first and then skewed.

http://jsfiddle.net/74ehh/2/
see comment as i got it

As you can see this messes up the result so instead of box that's little tilted and rotated. I get box that is rotated and tilted which's hard to comprehend and not what i wanted.

i tried changing order like so..

`transform: skew(30deg) rotate(30deg);`

but that didn't work.

or could someone elaborate on how would i go about calculating skew if box is rotated.

So what can i do?

Comment: "As you can see this messes up the result" No we can't see, can you provide a demo of your markup/CSS in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) maybe?

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/74ehh/1/

Comment: ok wait then ...im working on it

Comment: another question i asked before this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676996/why-css-rotate-messes-up-childs-skew

but now i get it

Comment: thanks to you guys i made something http://jsfiddle.net/74ehh/3/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/74ehh/4/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/f4xdT/14/ newer version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First about Order: it's from left to right. so in code...

`-webkit-transform: skew(30deg) rotate(30deg);`

it will get skewed first and then rotated.

what i was having trouble is that child elements were working with it...

what i found out is that it's actually that skew property is that is screwed (fortunately)?

to skew it doesn't matter how much parent of the element of the element itself is rotated to it north/top of monitor will always be 0degree.

Comment: "what i found out is that it's actually that skew property is that is screwed (fortunately)?" Uh... what?

Comment: basically i was thinking that if elem A has Elem B, and if i rotate elem A and the skew B it'd skew based on its parent but no it's based on real horizontal of screen.